# Plotting a curve fit causes axis labels to change

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following code to plot a curve fit:

```matlab
figure(1)
hold on
xlabel('hello')
ylabel('world')
xdata = [0;1]
ydata = [0;1]
datafit = fit(xdata,ydata,'line')
plot(datafit)
hold off
```

I expected the labels to stay as I defined them, but after the plot command they are changed to x and y. Why don't my defined labels stay? It works when I instead plot the xdata and ydata independently.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. The fast one is just to use `xlabel` and `ylabel` after `fit(...)` as follows:

```
figure(1)
hold on
xdata = [0;1]
ydata = [0;1]
datafit = fit(xdata,ydata,'line')
xlabel('hello')
ylabel('world')
hold off
```

2. You can also retrieve the fit data and use `plot` independly as you said. Then configure the axis labels.
3. You can use the plot Property Inspector to setup the axis labels and further visual configuration.

Comment: Thank you, obviously it's easy to fix this, but I was surprised by the behaviour. Why does the plot function behave differently when passed a cfit object than when passed simple x y data?

Comment: MATLAB `plot` function is able to process different type of objects. Consequently, depending on the type of object some figure propoerties are set in different ways. Nevertheless, MATLAB plotting is highly customizable to meet your requirements. You can modify all figure/axes/plot properties after it is created.